# Migrations creates extra keys and indexes

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core, ef-core-7.0

I've been working recently on setting up a code first database via EF Core 7.0.4 but I'm encountering a strange behavior when I run the migrations -> extra alternate keys and indexes are being generated and I don't get it. Let me walk you through it:

I've first worked on a SQL script for designing and architecting the database structure - tables, constraints and so on. Here's a mock of my SQL script:

```
CREATE TABLE [Product].[Family] 
(
    uid uniqueidentifier 
        CONSTRAINT [DF_Product_Family_UID] DEFAULT (NEWSEQUENTIALID()) ROWGUIDCOL NOT NULL,
    code int IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT FOR REPLICATION NOT NULL,
    description nvarchar(50) NOT NULL,
    created datetime 
        CONSTRAINT [DF_Product_Family_Created] DEFAULT GETDATE() NOT NULL,
    updated datetime 
        CONSTRAINT [DF_Product_Family_Updated] DEFAULT GETDATE() NOT NULL,
    inactive bit 
        CONSTRAINT [DF_Product_Family_Inactive] DEFAULT (0) NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_Product_Family_UID] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED (uid ASC)
)

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Product_Family_Code] 
ON [Product].[Family] (code ASC)
GO

CREATE TABLE [Product].[Category] 
(
    uid uniqueidentifier 
        CONSTRAINT [DF_Product_Category_UID] DEFAULT (NEWSEQUENTIALID()) ROWGUIDCOL NOT NULL,
    code int IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT FOR REPLICATION NOT NULL,
    description nvarchar(50) NOT NULL,
    fFamilyCode int NOT NULL,
    created datetime 
        CONSTRAINT [DF_Product_Category_Created] DEFAULT GETDATE() NOT NULL,
    updated datetime 
        CONSTRAINT [DF_Product_Category_Updated] DEFAULT GETDATE() NOT NULL,
    inactive bit 
        CONSTRAINT [DF_Product_Category_Inactive] DEFAULT (0) NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_Product_Category_UID] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED (uid ASC)
)

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Product_Category_Code] 
ON [Product].[Category] (code ASC)
GO

ALTER TABLE [Product].[Category]
    ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_Category_Product_Family] 
        FOREIGN KEY (fFamilyCode) REFERENCES [Product].[Family] (code)
```

Then, I replicated these SQL entities into models in the project solution:

```
public partial class Family
{
    [Column(Order = 0)]
    public Guid Uid { get; set; }
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    public int Code { get; set; }
    [Column(Order = 2)]
    public string Description { get; set; } = null!;
    [Column(Order = 3)]
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
    [Column(Order = 4)]
    public DateTime Updated { get; set; }
    [Column(Order = 5)]
    public bool Inactive { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Category> Categories { get; } = new List<Category>();

    public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; } = new List<Product>();

    public virtual ICollection<SubCategory> SubCategories { get; } = new List<SubCategory>();
}

public partial class Category
{
    [Column(Order = 0)]
    public Guid Uid { get; set; }
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    public int Code { get; set; }
    [Column(Order = 2)]
    public string Description { get; set; } = null!;
    [Column(Order = 3)]
    public int FFamilyCode { get; set; }
    [Column(Order = 4)]
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
    [Column(Order = 5)]
    public DateTime Updated { get; set; }
    [Column(Order = 6)]
    public bool Inactive { get; set; }

    public virtual Family FFamilyCodeNavigation { get; set; } = null!;
    public virtual ICollection<SubCategory> SubCategories { get; } = new List<SubCategory>();

    public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; } = new List<Product>();
}
```

And finally, the corresponding database sets:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Family>(entity =>
{
    entity.ToTable("Family", "Product");

    entity.HasKey(e => e.Uid)
        .HasName("PK_Product_Family_UID")
        .IsClustered(false);

    entity.HasIndex(e => e.Code, "IX_Product_Family_Code")
        .IsClustered();

    entity.Property(e => e.Uid)
        .HasDefaultValueSql("(newsequentialid())")
        .HasColumnName("uid");

    entity.Property(e => e.Code)
        .UseIdentityColumn(1, 1)
        .HasColumnName("code");

    entity.Property(e => e.Description)
        .HasMaxLength(50)
        .HasColumnName("description");

    entity.Property(e => e.Created)
        .HasDefaultValueSql("(getdate())")
        .HasColumnType("datetime")
        .HasColumnName("created");

    entity.Property(e => e.Updated)
        .HasDefaultValueSql("(getdate())")
        .HasColumnType("datetime")
        .HasColumnName("updated");

    entity.Property(e => e.Inactive)
        .HasDefaultValue(false)
        .HasColumnName("inactive");
});

modelBuilder.Entity<Category>(entity =>
{
    entity.ToTable("Category", "Product");

    entity.HasKey(e => e.Uid)
        .HasName("PK_Product_Category_UID")
        .IsClustered(false);

    entity.HasIndex(e => e.Code, "IX_Product_Category_Code")
        .IsUnique()
        .IsClustered();

    entity.Property(e => e.Uid)
        .HasDefaultValueSql("(newsequentialid())")
        .HasColumnName("uid");
    
    entity.Property(e => e.Code)
        .UseHiLo()
        .UseIdentityColumn(1, 1)
        .HasColumnName("code");

    entity.Property(e => e.Description)
        .HasMaxLength(50)
        .HasColumnName("description");

    entity.Property(e => e.FFamilyCode)
        .HasColumnName("fFamilyCode");
    
    entity.Property(e => e.Created)
        .HasDefaultValueSql("(getdate())")
        .HasColumnType("datetime")
        .HasColumnName("created");

    entity.Property(e => e.Updated)
        .HasDefaultValueSql("(getdate())")
        .HasColumnType("datetime")
        .HasColumnName("updated");

    entity.Property(e => e.Inactive)
        .HasDefaultValue(false)
        .HasColumnName("inactive");

    entity.HasOne(d => d.FFamilyCodeNavigation).WithMany(p => p.Categories)
        .HasForeignKey(d => d.FFamilyCode)
        .HasPrincipalKey(d => d.Code)
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict)
        .HasConstraintName("FK_Category_Product_Family");
});
```

Now, when I run the migrations for the `[Product].[Family]` table (and not only), another AK and an extra index is being generated. In addition, when it comes to `[Product].[Category]` table, an extra alternate key and since it is referencing the `[Product].[Family]` table, it creates two more indexes, as shown in this screenshot:

[image]

Since I couldn't tell immediately why is this happening, thought to see the actual SQL script that EF Core generates and runs against my server. And here is it:

```
CREATE TABLE [Product].[Family] 
(
    [uid] uniqueidentifier NOT NULL DEFAULT ((newsequentialid())),
    [code] int NOT NULL IDENTITY,
    [description] nvarchar(50) NOT NULL,
    [created] datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT ((getdate())),
    [updated] datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT ((getdate())),
    [inactive] bit NOT NULL DEFAULT CAST(0 AS bit),
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Product_Family_UID] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED ([uid]),
    CONSTRAINT [AK_Family_code] UNIQUE ([code])
);
GO

CREATE TABLE [Product].[Category] 
(
    [uid] uniqueidentifier NOT NULL DEFAULT ((newsequentialid())),
    [code] int NOT NULL IDENTITY,
    [description] nvarchar(50) NOT NULL,
    [fFamilyCode] int NOT NULL,
    [created] datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT ((getdate())),
    [updated] datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT ((getdate())),
    [inactive] bit NOT NULL DEFAULT CAST(0 AS bit),
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Product_Category_UID] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED ([uid]),
    CONSTRAINT [AK_Category_code] UNIQUE ([code]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Category_Product_Family] FOREIGN KEY ([fFamilyCode]) REFERENCES [Product].[Family] ([code]) ON DELETE NO ACTION
);
GO

CREATE INDEX [IX_Category_fFamilyCode] ON [Product].[Category] ([fFamilyCode]);
GO

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Product_Category_Code] ON [Product].[Category] ([code]);
GO
```

Now, I have the answer about the extra indexes that are being created - because of the `UNIQUE CONSTRAINT` but I really don't understand why EF Core does this and also, why it creates extra alternate keys? Here's how the two tables would/should look like if I just run the SQL script created by myself and not the one that EF Core uses:

[image]

Can anyone help me understand and fix it?

### Edit upon the answer received from Ivan

Please allow me to break your answer:

> 1. EF Core supports only FKs referencing key (primary or alternate) in the principal entity. This is different from relational database which
>    only require unique key in the referenced table.

I may be crazy or naive, but wasn't supposed to fall under the relational database rules?

> 2. EF Core alternate key has the same requirements as primary key - non null, not mutable after insert and backed with unique
>    constraint/index. The only difference from primary key is that
>    alternate keys by default imply non clustered index.

True.

> 3. Whenever you use HasPrincipalKey API, if the referenced field is not primary or alternate key, EF will create alternate key for you,
>    with default conventional constraint/index names.

Yeah, I could see that but that's fine, I don't mind about the key itself.

### Anyhow, let's dive into your proposed solution

So, as per your recommendation to change the property from `.HasIndex()` to `.HasAlternateKey()`, I've already tried it before. The database sets now look like this:

**Family**

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<Family>(entity =>
        {
            entity.ToTable("Family", "Product");

            entity.HasKey(e => e.Uid)
                .HasName("PK_Product_Family_UID")
                .IsClustered(false);

            entity.HasAlternateKey(e => e.Code)
                .HasName("IX_Product_Family_Code")
                .IsClustered();

            entity.Property(e => e.Uid)
                .HasDefaultValueSql("(newsequentialid())")
                .HasColumnName("uid");

            entity.Property(e => e.Code)
                .UseIdentityColumn(1, 1)
                .HasColumnName("code");

            entity.Property(e => e.Description)
                .HasMaxLength(50)
                .HasColumnName("description");

            entity.Property(e => e.Created)
                .HasDefaultValueSql("(getdate())")
                .HasColumnType("datetime")
                .HasColumnName("created");

            entity.Property(e => e.Updated)
                .HasDefaultValueSql("(getdate())")
                .HasColumnType("datetime")
                .HasColumnName("updated");

            entity.Property(e => e.Inactive)
                .HasDefaultValue(false)
                .HasColumnName("inactive");
        });
```

**Category**

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<Category>(entity =>
        {
            entity.ToTable("Category", "Product");

            entity.HasKey(e => e.Uid)
                .HasName("PK_Product_Category_UID")
                .IsClustered(false);

            entity.HasAlternateKey(e => e.Code)
                .HasName("IX_Product_Category_Code")
                .IsClustered();

            entity.Property(e => e.Uid)
                .HasDefaultValueSql("(newsequentialid())")
                .HasColumnName("uid");

            entity.Property(e => e.Code)
                .UseIdentityColumn(1, 1)
                .HasColumnName("code");

            entity.Property(e => e.Description)
                .HasMaxLength(50)
                .HasColumnName("description");

            entity.Property(e => e.FFamilyCode)
                .HasColumnName("fFamilyCode");

            entity.Property(e => e.Created)
                .HasDefaultValueSql("(getdate())")
                .HasColumnType("datetime")
                .HasColumnName("created");

            entity.Property(e => e.Updated)
                .HasDefaultValueSql("(getdate())")
                .HasColumnType("datetime")
                .HasColumnName("updated");

            entity.Property(e => e.Inactive)
                .HasDefaultValue(false)
                .HasColumnName("inactive");

            entity.HasOne(d => d.FFamilyCodeNavigation).WithMany(p => p.Categories)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.FFamilyCode)
                .HasPrincipalKey(d => d.Code)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict)
                .HasConstraintName("FK_Category_Product_Family");
        });
```

The generated migration

```
            migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "Family",
                schema: "Product",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    uid = table.Column<Guid>(type: "uniqueidentifier", nullable: false, defaultValueSql: "(newsequentialid())"),
                    code = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false)
                        .Annotation("SqlServer:Identity", "1, 1"),
                    description = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(50)", maxLength: 50, nullable: false),
                    created = table.Column<DateTime>(type: "datetime", nullable: false, defaultValueSql: "(getdate())"),
                    updated = table.Column<DateTime>(type: "datetime", nullable: false, defaultValueSql: "(getdate())"),
                    inactive = table.Column<bool>(type: "bit", nullable: false, defaultValue: false)
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_Product_Family_UID", x => x.uid)
                        .Annotation("SqlServer:Clustered", false);
                    table.UniqueConstraint("IX_Product_Family_Code", x => x.code)
                        .Annotation("SqlServer:Clustered", true);
                });

            migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "Category",
                schema: "Product",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    uid = table.Column<Guid>(type: "uniqueidentifier", nullable: false, defaultValueSql: "(newsequentialid())"),
                    code = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false)
                        .Annotation("SqlServer:Identity", "1, 1"),
                    description = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(50)", maxLength: 50, nullable: false),
                    fFamilyCode = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false),
                    created = table.Column<DateTime>(type: "datetime", nullable: false, defaultValueSql: "(getdate())"),
                    updated = table.Column<DateTime>(type: "datetime", nullable: false, defaultValueSql: "(getdate())"),
                    inactive = table.Column<bool>(type: "bit", nullable: false, defaultValue: false)
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_Product_Category_UID", x => x.uid)
                        .Annotation("SqlServer:Clustered", false);
                    table.UniqueConstraint("IX_Product_Category_Code", x => x.code)
                        .Annotation("SqlServer:Clustered", true);
                    table.ForeignKey(
                        name: "FK_Category_Product_Family",
                        column: x => x.fFamilyCode,
                        principalSchema: "Product",
                        principalTable: "Family",
                        principalColumn: "code",
                        onDelete: ReferentialAction.Restrict);
                });

            migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
                name: "IX_Category_fFamilyCode",
                schema: "Product",
                table: "Category",
                column: "fFamilyCode");
```

And... finally the DDL script output from the migration:

```
CREATE TABLE [Product].[Family] (
    [uid] uniqueidentifier NOT NULL DEFAULT ((newsequentialid())),
    [code] int NOT NULL IDENTITY,
    [description] nvarchar(50) NOT NULL,
    [created] datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT ((getdate())),
    [updated] datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT ((getdate())),
    [inactive] bit NOT NULL DEFAULT CAST(0 AS bit),
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Product_Family_UID] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED ([uid]),
    CONSTRAINT [IX_Product_Family_Code] UNIQUE CLUSTERED ([code])
);
GO

CREATE TABLE [Product].[Category] (
    [uid] uniqueidentifier NOT NULL DEFAULT ((newsequentialid())),
    [code] int NOT NULL IDENTITY,
    [description] nvarchar(50) NOT NULL,
    [fFamilyCode] int NOT NULL,
    [created] datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT ((getdate())),
    [updated] datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT ((getdate())),
    [inactive] bit NOT NULL DEFAULT CAST(0 AS bit),
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Product_Category_UID] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED ([uid]),
    CONSTRAINT [IX_Product_Category_Code] UNIQUE CLUSTERED ([code]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Category_Product_Family] FOREIGN KEY ([fFamilyCode]) REFERENCES [Product].[Family] ([code]) ON DELETE NO ACTION
);
GO

CREATE INDEX [IX_Category_fFamilyCode] ON [Product].[Category] ([fFamilyCode]);
GO
```

As you can see, the `UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX ON [Product].[Category]` is missing in my case from the DDL compared to what you got.

Anyway, I ran the command to update the database. And it looks like this:

[image]

Conclusions:

1. Yeah, I got rid of the extra index created on `[Product].[Family]` table as previously it was getting created.
2. I still get the extra index on `[Product].[Category]` table targeting the `FK` (as shown in the screenshot).
3. What's weird though is, if I right click on `[Product].[Category]` table via SSMS and script it as `CREATE TO -> New query window` to see the actual script behind it, it looks like this:

```
/****** Object:  Table [Product].[Category]    Script Date: 14-03-2024 11:31:02 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [Product].[Category](
    [uid] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [code] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [description] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [fFamilyCode] [int] NOT NULL,
    [created] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [updated] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [inactive] [bit] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Product_Category_UID] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [uid] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY],
 CONSTRAINT [IX_Product_Category_Code] UNIQUE CLUSTERED 
(
    [code] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [Product].[Category] ADD  DEFAULT (newsequentialid()) FOR [uid]
GO

ALTER TABLE [Product].[Category] ADD  DEFAULT (getdate()) FOR [created]
GO

ALTER TABLE [Product].[Category] ADD  DEFAULT (getdate()) FOR [updated]
GO

ALTER TABLE [Product].[Category] ADD  DEFAULT (CONVERT([bit],(0))) FOR [inactive]
GO

ALTER TABLE [Product].[Category]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Category_Product_Family] FOREIGN KEY([fFamilyCode])
REFERENCES [Product].[Family] ([code])
GO

ALTER TABLE [Product].[Category] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Category_Product_Family]
GO
```

... there is no `CONSTRAINT` that would generate the `IX_Category_fFamilyCode` non-unique, non-clustered index.

4. Am I missing anything from your recommendation?

Comment: That's a unique index created for the unique constraint which is something expected. If you manually create a unique constraint it will also create a unique index.

Comment: @Eldar didn't I say that already, that I get it? I just want not to have them created but replicate the `SQL` behavior and also avoid the extra `AKs` created

Comment: Why not just make 'uid' the clustered PK and get rid of the redundant key `code`?

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft it's the requirement for merges and so on. And yes, the issue that it broughts when it come to indexes based on an `uniqueidentifier` column.

Comment: I don't *know* why it changes the implementation slightly, but I can provide a hypothesis and a way to test it. Your original implementation says that `Product.Category.fFamilyCode` is a foreign key, but there is no key in your original `Product.Family` table for it to be a foreign key _to_. Sure, it is legal to create a foreign key to a unique index, but entity framework is presumably saying "if something is foreign keying to this code column, then I am going to explicitly make it a key, not just an index". This can be tested by temporarily eliminating the foreign key constraint.

Comment: @allmhuran yeah, I get that. Once a `unique constraint` is created, then automatically the index. However, I get two indexes created in `[Product].[Family]` table. Why is so? Also, `EF Core` generates after all a script to run against the server, right? So, now let me ask you - why does `EF Core` generates a different script than the one I wrote myself? The logic of my script is `SQL` standard and accordingly.

Comment: "Once a unique constraint is created, then automatically the index" - indeed, but not relevant to my comment. I'm suggesting the opposite causality: "because an index was created, and a foreign key to it was created, EF converted the index to a constraint". There's a subtlety here. Yes, a unique index can legally act as the "foreign" part of a foreign key without being created as a constraint backed by an automatic index. But there *is* a difference: In the EF implementation, the `AK_Category_code` appears in the "keys" folder. In your implementation it's "just" an index.

Comment: @allmhuran then how do I fix and avoid having this behavior?

Comment: Why do you want to fix it? Indeed, I would say the EF implementation is more accurate, semantically: A "foreign key" is "a _key_ in a foreign (ie, some other) table", so it created that key as an explicit key, rather than just an implicit one.

Comment: @allmhuran because I have two indexes created that would require long term management (i.e. fragmentation, rebuilding etc.)? I understand the alternate key, it's fine, but I would rather avoid more indexes. And these two tables are just an example, there are other tables for which more indexes are being created by EF and basically, doubling them.

Comment: I wonder what happens if, in your original script, you make `code` the primary key clustered on `Family`, and put a unique nonclustered index on `uid` (rather than putting the primary key nonclustered on `uid` and a unique index on `code`). If my hypothesis is right, then EF wouldn't create an additional element, since the foreign key would be referencing something that is alredy an explicit key.

Comment: @allmhuran didn't try but I won't even. The requirements are those above and EF Core is not generating the migration as it's supposed to. Again, I can understand the extra `alternate key` but I do not want the extra index (indices) created. I just don't want them.

Comment: OK. Ivan has now provided an answer confirming my hypothesis, and with my approach you don't get any "extra" indexes. But if you have some other reason for making the original design requirements strictly immutable despite these facts, then I guess it's your move.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, let remove `SubCategories` and `Products` collections, since they reference entities not included in the post, and concentrate only on `Family` and `Category` models and their relationship.

Now some facts:

1. EF Core supports only FKs referencing *key* (primary or alternate) in the principal entity. This is different from relational database which only require *unique key* in the referenced table.
2. EF Core alternate key has the same requirements as primary key - non null, not mutable after insert and backed with unique constraint/index. The only difference from primary key is that alternate keys by default imply non clustered index.
3. Whenever you use `HasPrincipalKey` API, if the referenced field is not primary or alternate key, EF will create alternate key for you, with *default conventional* constraint/index names.

The last is what is causing the unexpected unique constraint and index in you case. Because of this line

```cs
entity.HasOne(d => d.FFamilyCodeNavigation).WithMany(p => p.Categories)
    .HasForeignKey(d => d.FFamilyCode)
    .HasPrincipalKey(d => d.Code) // <--
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict)
    .HasConstraintName("FK_Category_Product_Family");
```

Even though you have configured unique index, it is not using the conventional name which in this particular case is ""AK_Family_code", so EF creates new one "for you".

One may consider this as bug, but it is what it is, and there is a simple solution - instead of letting EF create alternate key for you, create and configure explicitly such key instead of unique index.

In your case, it's a matter of replacing

```cs
entity.HasIndex(e => e.Code, "IX_Product_Family_Code")
    .IsClustered();
```

with

```cs
entity.HasAlternateKey(e => e.Code)
    .HasName("IX_Product_Family_Code")
    .IsClustered();
```

Now the generated migration should be like this

```cs
migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
    name: "Family",
    schema: "Product",
    columns: table => new
    {
        uid = table.Column<Guid>(type: "uniqueidentifier", nullable: false, defaultValueSql: "(newsequentialid())"),
        code = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false)
            .Annotation("SqlServer:Identity", "1, 1"),
        description = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(50)", maxLength: 50, nullable: false),
        created = table.Column<DateTime>(type: "datetime", nullable: false, defaultValueSql: "(getdate())"),
        updated = table.Column<DateTime>(type: "datetime", nullable: false, defaultValueSql: "(getdate())"),
        inactive = table.Column<bool>(type: "bit", nullable: false, defaultValue: false)
    },
    constraints: table =>
    {
        table.PrimaryKey("PK_Product_Family_UID", x => x.uid)
            .Annotation("SqlServer:Clustered", false);
        table.UniqueConstraint("IX_Product_Family_Code", x => x.code)
            .Annotation("SqlServer:Clustered", true);
    });

migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
    name: "Category",
    schema: "Product",
    columns: table => new
    {
        uid = table.Column<Guid>(type: "uniqueidentifier", nullable: false, defaultValueSql: "(newsequentialid())"),
        code = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false)
            .Annotation("SqlServer:Identity", "1, 1"),
        description = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(50)", maxLength: 50, nullable: false),
        fFamilyCode = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false),
        created = table.Column<DateTime>(type: "datetime", nullable: false, defaultValueSql: "(getdate())"),
        updated = table.Column<DateTime>(type: "datetime", nullable: false, defaultValueSql: "(getdate())"),
        inactive = table.Column<bool>(type: "bit", nullable: false, defaultValue: false)
    },
    constraints: table =>
    {
        table.PrimaryKey("PK_Product_Category_UID", x => x.uid)
            .Annotation("SqlServer:Clustered", false);
        table.ForeignKey(
            name: "FK_Category_Product_Family",
            column: x => x.fFamilyCode,
            principalSchema: "Product",
            principalTable: "Family",
            principalColumn: "code",
            onDelete: ReferentialAction.Restrict);
    });

migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
    name: "IX_Category_fFamilyCode",
    schema: "Product",
    table: "Category",
    column: "fFamilyCode");

migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
    name: "IX_Product_Category_Code",
    schema: "Product",
    table: "Category",
    column: "code",
    unique: true)
    .Annotation("SqlServer:Clustered", true);
```

and DDL (extracted with `Script-Migration` command):

```sql
CREATE TABLE [Product].[Family] (
    [uid] uniqueidentifier NOT NULL DEFAULT ((newsequentialid())),
    [code] int NOT NULL IDENTITY,
    [description] nvarchar(50) NOT NULL,
    [created] datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT ((getdate())),
    [updated] datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT ((getdate())),
    [inactive] bit NOT NULL DEFAULT CAST(0 AS bit),
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Product_Family_UID] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED ([uid]),
    CONSTRAINT [IX_Product_Family_Code] UNIQUE CLUSTERED ([code])
);
GO

CREATE TABLE [Product].[Category] (
    [uid] uniqueidentifier NOT NULL DEFAULT ((newsequentialid())),
    [code] int NOT NULL IDENTITY,
    [description] nvarchar(50) NOT NULL,
    [fFamilyCode] int NOT NULL,
    [created] datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT ((getdate())),
    [updated] datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT ((getdate())),
    [inactive] bit NOT NULL DEFAULT CAST(0 AS bit),
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Product_Category_UID] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED ([uid]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Category_Product_Family] FOREIGN KEY ([fFamilyCode]) REFERENCES [Product].[Family] ([code]) ON DELETE NO ACTION
);
GO

CREATE INDEX [IX_Category_fFamilyCode] ON [Product].[Category] ([fFamilyCode]);
GO

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Product_Category_Code] ON [Product].[Category] ([code]);
GO
```

which is what is expected. Problem solved.

Just keep in mind that even though database allow modifying `Family.Code` column, EF core won't because of the alternate key requirements/constraints.

Most of this is explained with examples in [Alternate Keys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/keys?tabs=data-annotations#alternate-keys) section of the official EF Core documentation.

**Update:** Regarding the "extra" non unique index on FK column ("IX_Category_fFamilyCode").

Creating non unique index for FK columns is considered a good practice, as it helps database enforcing the FK constraint, performing SQL joins for querying child "collection", cascade delete (when used) etc. EF is strictly following that practice and does not allow you to remove such indexes even with fluent/model APIs. And probably this is how it should be - these indexes really help.

Comment: Please check my updates.

Comment: My results are not the same as yours @Ivan. I'm talking about what I get after running the migration and therefore the DDL script -> it's not the same as yours. Also, what do you think about the fact that the actual table, after updating the database, when I script its definition, it does not include that extra index, although it's there. What am I missing here?

Comment: I'm not sure.  The migration and DDL I've included in the answer were generated from exact classes (with only aforementioned collection navigation collections commented out) and the modified fluent configuration from your post, into clean db context without anything else. Using latest EF 8.0.3 if that matters. I haven't applied it to the SqlServer database, but I'm assuming it would execute the same script. What is your EF version (sometimes this matters)?

Comment: The version I'm using is 7.03. Also please check again in my question, the bullet 3 after updating upon your answer.

Comment: I saw it. There seem to be a bug or issue with "Script As -> CREATE TO" command as it doesn't show the actual DDL. At the same time, "View Designer" shows the correct script which corresponds to what you see in tree view - Indexes and Keys nodes for a table. So all good. What else? The unique index "IX_Product_Family_Code" is not really missing, it is created implicitly from "CONSTRAINT [IX_Product_Family_Code] UNIQUE CLUSTERED ([code] ASC)". And again, don't look at database, use EF Core `Script-Migration' PMC (or corresponding CLI) command to get the DDL which is executed by EF migration.

Comment: About your statement "Creating non unique index for FK columns is considered a good practice" -> this has some trade-offs such as the `INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE` operations can be slowed down. Also, more storage is require (potentially) and maintenance. I am still confused about why `EF` does this just based on a recommendation rather than stick to the basics of `SQL` and let it optional to you to implement the recommendations. Instead, it implements them and you need to alter/modify manually the `migration` file before updating the DB.

Comment: I did grant you the bounty as your answer pretty much nailed down how `EF` works. Thanks!